# Putting Git hooks into a repository

Tags: git, hook, githooks

Is it considered to be a bad practice - to put `.git/hooks` into the projects repository (using symlinks, for example). If yes, what is the best way to deliver same hooks to different Git users?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the projects repository"* (or perhaps *"the project's repository"* (possessive))? Does it refer to a particular IDE? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen what is meant by project in this question is something existing as a VCS root one can clone and start to work with.

Comment: The term used in this context [may have arisen from GitLab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Rb8LXftWDk&t=3m24s).

Comment: @PeterMortensen GitLab launched in 2014 while the question was asked in Aug'11, so the term precedes GitLab existence )

Comment: It would be a nice feature for git to add. Upon cloning a repo, if it contains a `.git-suggested` directory, prompt the user if they would like to copy its contents into `.git/{hooks,config,info,(whatever is safe)}`. Smoothly handling updates to suggested hooks would be tricky, though.

Answer (score 178):

Nowadays you can do the following to set a directory that is under version control to be your Git hooks directory, e.g., `MY_REPO_DIR/.githooks` would be

```
git config --local core.hooksPath .githooks/
```

It is still not directly enforceable but, if you add a note in your README (or whatever), this requires a minimum of effort on each developer's part.

Comment: One trick I found on https://www.viget.com/articles/two-ways-to-share-git-hooks-with-your-team/ is to set the option from your Makefile/CMake config/whatever.

Comment: As a note, this only works for versions of git above 2.9.0. This wasn't a "thing" at the time of the post.

Comment: This option cannot be included in a .gitattributes files, I guess?

Answer (score 166):

I generally agree [with Scy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-a-repository/3462998#3462998), with a couple of additional suggestions, enough that it's worth a separate answer.

First, you should write a script which creates the appropriate symlinks, especially if these hooks are about enforcing policy or creating useful notifications. People will be much more likely to use the hooks if they can just type `bin/create-hook-symlinks` than if they have to do it themselves.

Second, directly symlinking hooks prevents users from adding in their own personal hooks. For example, I rather like the sample pre-commit hook which makes sure I don't have any white space errors. A great way around this is to drop in a hook wrapper script in your repository, and symlink *all* of the hooks to it.

The wrapper can then examine `$0` (assuming it's a Bash script; an equivalent like `argv[0]` otherwise) to figure out which hook it was invoked as, then invoke the appropriate hook within your repository, as well as the appropriate user's hook, which will have to be renamed, passing all the arguments to each. Quick example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ -x $0.local ]; then
    $0.local "$@" || exit $?
fi
if [ -x tracked_hooks/$(basename $0) ]; then
    tracked_hooks/$(basename $0) "$@" || exit $?
fi
```

The installation script would move all pre-existing hooks to the side (append `.local` to their names), and symlink all known hook names to the above script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
HOOK_NAMES="applypatch-msg pre-applypatch post-applypatch pre-commit prepare-commit-msg commit-msg post-commit pre-rebase post-checkout post-merge pre-receive update post-receive post-update pre-auto-gc"
HOOK_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/hooks

for hook in $HOOK_NAMES; do
    # If the hook already exists, is executable, and is not a symlink
    if [ ! -h $HOOK_DIR/$hook -a -x $HOOK_DIR/$hook ]; then
        mv $HOOK_DIR/$hook $HOOK_DIR/$hook.local
    fi
    # create the symlink, overwriting the file if it exists
    # probably the only way this would happen is if you're using an old version of git
    # -- back when the sample hooks were not executable, instead of being named ____.sample
    ln -s -f ../../bin/hooks-wrapper $HOOK_DIR/$hook
done
```

Comment: I added `chmod +x .git/hooks/*` to your `bin/create-hook-symlinks`  to work it.

Comment: @guneysus You shouldn't need that, because the hooks should already be executable (they should be checked in that way) and the links don't need any special permissions, just the files they link to.

Comment: A better way to get the hook dir is `HOOK_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/hooks`.

Comment: I've put together a simple system based on this to manage the hooks in my project: http://ell.io/tt$Paws.js/blob/Master/Scripts/install-git-hooks.sh

Comment: the risk of overwriting old git sample files (or possibly the users own disabled hooks!) is easily avoidable by testing for file (-f) instead of executable (-x) when renaming. The wrapper tests for executable upon invocation anyway, which is the most sensible time to test this.

Comment: I took just the essentials and put it in a repo https://github.com/sjungwirth/githooks

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels, any trick for '--separate-git-dir', where .git is just a "pseudo symlink" to the repo located outside of the working tree?

Comment: @Sz, No I've never used a setup like that. Sorry.

Comment: The installation script won't work for linked worktrees as `$HOOK_DIR` will be wrong.  Using `HOOK_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-common-dir)/hooks` instead should work.

Comment: Symlinks are a problem for Windows users (or at least they were the last time I was forced to use Windows at a corporate gig, and AFAIK it hasn't changed). Of course if Windows users are using the built-in Bash support, I would guess that everything should work.

Answer (score 138):

No, putting them into the repository is fine. I’d even suggest doing so (if they are useful for others as well). The user has to explicitly enable them (as you said, for example, by symlinking), which is on one hand a bit of a pain, but it protects users on the other hand from running arbitrary code without their consent.

Comment: what if it is a company policy thing, then the code is not "arbitrary" this is required code, so this would be considered a limitation in GIT, for not having another (pre-defined) directory, which is tracked, which also gets executed along with the regular hooks

Comment: Automatically delivering hooks is a security issue, I'm glad that Git doesn't do it directly - to enforce team/company policy, use hooks on the server side or let users manually decide to enable them as @scy describes :)

Comment: "protects users [...] from running arbitrary code without their consent". If a developer would do like you suggest (symlinking) then the hook could be changed by someone else, and run "arbitrary code without their consent"

Comment: MiniGod: Of course. If you’re sufficiently paranoid, you could copy the hooks instead of symlinking them, then audit them, and only then enable them. However, most (citation needed) Git repositories will contain source code which is to be run on the user’s machine, so you’re likely to run constantly changing, unaudited code anyway. But yes, you’ve got a point. ;)

Answer (score 13):

### Store in the project and install in the build

As others state in their answer, *if* your hooks are specific for your particular projects then include them in the project itself, managed by Git. I would take this even further and say that, given that it is good practice to have your project build using a single script or command, your hooks should be installed during the build.

I wrote an article about [managing Git hooks](https://www.rudikershaw.com/articles/git-hooks-and-java), if you are interested in reading about this in a little more depth.

### Java & Maven

***Full disclaimer; I wrote the [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) plugin described below.***

If you are handling build management with Maven for your Java projects, the following Maven plugin handles installing hooks from a location in your project.

https://github.com/rudikershaw/git-build-hook

Put all your Git hooks in a directory in your project, and then configure your `pom.xml` to include the following plugin declaration, goal, and configuration.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.rudikershaw.gitbuildhook</groupId>
      <artifactId>git-build-hook-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <gitConfig>
          <!-- The location of the directory you are using to store the Git hooks in your project. -->
          <core.hooksPath>hooks-directory/</core.hooksPath>
        </gitConfig>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <!-- Sets git config specified under configuration > gitConfig. -->
            <goal>configure</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
      <!-- ... etc ... -->
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When you run your project build, the plugin will configure Git to run hooks out of the directory specified. This will effectively set up the hooks in that directory for everyone working on your project.

### JavaScript & NPM

For NPM there is a dependency called [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) which allows you to install hooks including ones written in JavaScript.

```
// package.json
{
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm test",
      "pre-push": "npm test",
      "...": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

### Others

Additionally, there are a number of different hook management applications/plugins including [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) for Python projects, [Overcommit](https://github.com/sds/overcommit) for Ruby projects, and [Lefthook](https://github.com/Arkweid/lefthook) for Ruby *or* [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) projects.

Comment: Thanks for creating this plugin, it made integrating my pre-commit file super easy.

Comment: Husky is really great. I've even worked on PHP projects that used Husky just to manage pre-commit hooks that ran tools installed by Composer, such as phpstan and phpcs, and I was pretty happy with that setup. Composer doesn't have anything quite the same, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

From *[TEMPLATE DIRECTORY](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory)*, you could use one of these mechanisms to update the *.git/hooks* directory of each newly created Git repository:

> The template directory contains files and directories that will be
> copied to the $GIT_DIR after it is created.
>
> The template directory will be one of the following (in order):
>
> - the argument given with the *--template* option;
> - the contents of the *$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR* environment variable;
> - the *init.templateDir* configuration variable; or
> - the default template directory: */usr/share/git-core/templates*.

Answer (score 5):

For [PHP Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software))-based PHP projects, you can automatically distribute to engineers. Here is an example for pre-commit and commit-msg hooks.

Create a `hooks` folder, and then in your *composer.json* file:

```
 },
 "scripts": {
     "post-install-cmd": [
         "cp -r 'hooks/' '.git/hooks/'",
         "php -r \"copy('hooks/pre-commit', '.git/hooks/pre-commit');\"",
         "php -r \"copy('hooks/commit-msg', '.git/hooks/commit-msg');\"",
         "php -r \"chmod('.git/hooks/pre-commit', 0777);\"",
         "php -r \"chmod('.git/hooks/commit-msg', 0777);\"",
     ],
```

Then you can even update them as the project continues as everyone is running `composer install` on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4):

The *[pre-commit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit)* [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) package handles this elegantly, allowing you to specify pre-commit hooks in your *package.json* file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script, *add-git-hook.sh*, which you can ship as a regular file in the repository and can be executed to append the Git hook to the script file. Adjust which hook to use (pre-commit, post-commit, pre-push, etc.) and the definition of the hook in the cat heredoc.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Adds the git-hook described below. Appends to the hook file
# if it already exists or creates the file if it does not.
# Note: CWD must be inside target repository

HOOK_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/hooks
HOOK_FILE="$HOOK_DIR"/post-commit

# Create script file if doesn't exist
if [ ! -e "$HOOK_FILE" ] ; then
        echo '#!/usr/bin/bash' >> "$HOOK_FILE"
        chmod 700 "$HOOK_FILE"
fi

# Append hook code into script
cat >> "$HOOK_FILE" <<EOF

########################################
# ... post-commit hook script here ... #
########################################

EOF
```

This script might make sense to have executable permissions or the user can run it directly. I used this to automatically git-pull on other machines after I committed.

<sub>I answered the easier question which wasn't what was asked and wasn't what the OP was looking for. I opined on the use cases and arguments for shipping hook scripts in the repository versus managing them externally in the comments below.</sub>

Comment: I appreciate your effort and do believe there's a valuable information here however  - it does not answer the question stated.

Comment: In my opinion, if the hooks are specific to a particular repository or are integral components of the workflows used then they belong in the repository as files. It's hard to put them anywhere else without creating more problems than it solves. You could store general hooks in a repository of it's own or on a shared drive which could keep the project repo squeaky clean but at the cost of being much less practical. I agree with the other users in saying that the hooks must be easy to add. Symbolic links may create unnecessary dependence on a particular system or file structure.

Comment: Additionally, symbolic links break the users ability to add their own hooks. The .git/hooks directory isn't tracked so the source should start in the repository and make it's way into the hooks script, not the other way around. I think the counter-argument would be that the git hooks are more related to the workflow or team rather than the project and thus don't belong in the repository. Depending on your specific use-case, are you more okay with potentially polluting the git repository with less-related hooks or would you rather forego a bunch of complexity in putting them somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a lot of the posts are out of date, at least if you're using pre-commit in the python ecosystem (+ I found that changing the git hook path fails with slightly older versions of git, e.g. 2.3). With a .pre-commit-config.yaml in a hooks dir in the root of your repo, the easiest solution is to run:

```
pre-commit install -f --config hooks/.pre-commit-config.yaml
```

Comment: Where does .pre-commit-config.yaml come from? This answers needs a bit more info.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a managed solution for pre-commit hook management like [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/).
Or a centralized solution for server-side git-hooks like [Datree.io](https://datree.io/solutions/devops-policy/).

It has built-in policies like:

1. Detect and prevent [merging of secrets](https://docs.datree.io/docs/do-not-include-secret-files).
2. Enforce proper [Git user configuration](https://docs.datree.io/docs/unverified-users).
3. Enforce [Jira ticket integration](https://docs.datree.io/docs/link-pull-request-to-a-jira-ticket) - mention ticket number in pull request name / commit message.

It won't replace all of your hooks, but it might help your developers with the most obvious ones without the configuration hell of installing the hooks on every developer's computer/repository.

Disclaimer: I am one of Datrees founders

Comment: I think you are making an interesting product but I also think this does not answers the question and basically  is a self-promotion and nothing more.

Comment: This answer is about some framework or package, whereas the question is about Git Hooks - two different things.