# How to propagate Git Hooks while cloning

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, git-clone, propagation

I've written a pre-commit hook in my central repository. When my clients clone the repository it never propagates the hooks. I would like the hooks to also be copied to my clients' repositories. My clients are Windows users, using msysgit as the git client.

Is there any way I can get the hooks copied to local repositories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git hooks - propagating from remote repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471028/git-hooks-propagating-from-remote-repository)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository (although the symlink suggestion may not work on Windows...)

Answer (score 12):

You could write a setup script, e.g. setuphooks.sh, that pulls down the hook scripts and installs them in the right places.  It shouldn't be hard to write, as `curl` could do most of the work.

Or you could just include the hooks in the repo in a normal folder like `.hooks`, and copy them all to `.git/hooks`.

Others have suggested you symlink them, but that poses problems for users of Windows.

You can also [configure Git to use a different directory for your hook scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281447/241142)

```
git config --local core.hooksPath .hooks/
```

Answer (score 11):

Simple way, but half method. ;-)

I'm using Git on Windows.

1. Find the folder where git is installed.
2. Find the sub-folder "share\git-core\templates\hooks"
3. Copy the hook scripts there that you want.
   That folder contains hook script samples, generated in new Git repos by the `git init` command.
4. If you use the `git clone` command then the hooks folder contains the files that you copied on step 3.

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks! Note that the same folder in Linux is located under `/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks`.

Comment: what does the sentence `I'm used in Windows Git.` mean? I'm sure there's a typo in there, but don't know exactly what you meant

Comment: I guess it is the same to say " I am using git on Windows"