# Can I had git hook files to the repository so everybody has them

Tags: git, hook

I have a git hook file

.git/hooks/commit-msg

that I would like everybody on the team to have. Can I add it to the reposity somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

Comment: Another strongly-related question: [Putting Git hooks into repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository/3464399#3464399)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can't directly add the hook to the repository. However you can put the script in the normal tree structure and create a small script to link it to the hooks directory. If you have your `commit-msg-hook-script` is at the root of your repository, you could create an `install_commit_hook.sh`, with something like this:

```
ln -s ../../commit-msg-hook-script .git/hooks/commit-msg
```