# Symlink to folder with custom hooks in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I've got GitLab 8.16.4 and there are many groups with many projects. I'd like to create one location with many scripts run in loop as different hooks (just like in this solution [Chaining git hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730514/chaining-git-hooks/8734391#8734391)) and in each project make `custom_hooks` folder as a symlink to that earlier mentioned location.

I've got test project: `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/test/test.git/`. If I create there folder with hook (`/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/test/test.git/custom_hooks/update`) it's invoked. But if folder is symlink to other location hook isn't invoked.

I checked owners of folders/files, but they are ok.

Project:

`lrwxrwxrwx   1 gitlab gitlab     31 Feb  6 13:37 custom_hooks -> /home/user/custom_hooks`

/home/user/custom_hooks:

`drwxr-xr-x 2 gitlab       gitlab        4096 Feb  6 13:31 custom_hooks`

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 gitlab gitlab 10 Feb  6 13:26 /home/user/custom_hooks/update -> hook-chain`

Is there anything wrong with my configuration or maybe GitLab doesn't allow to invoke hooks from other localisation than files within project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

1. in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/` create folders `post-receive.d`, `pre-receive.d`, `update.d` and `myhooks`
2. in `myhooks` create `hook-chain` script and proper hooks to run by it
3. in first three folders create symlinks to script `hook-chain` in `myhooks`, like:

   ```
   [root@server ~]# ll /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/update.d/
   total 4
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 gitlab gitlab 68 Apr 18 08:47 update -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/myhooks/hook-chain
   ```
4. of course user `gitlab` has to be owner of all scripts

Comment: Does GitLab actually have to be the owner of the scripts - or just have the execute permission on the file?

Comment: @Shadow Execute permission probably should be enough. I change owner. Which is done automatically by dedicated script.

Comment: Confirmed, execute is enough. I now have have gitLab-runner on the same server which updates these scripts as part of a CI job, so the user doesn't have permissions to change ownership.