# Are git hooks pushed to the remote when I 'git push'?

Tags: git, githooks

If I create a new hook script in my local repository in repo/.git/hooks/post-commit and then I run "git push" are the hooks pushed to the remote?  Then, when the other developers run "git pull" from the same origin will they get my new hooks?

Comment: Perhaps this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository

Comment: Related (with very useful answers): [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427207/3258851)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

No. Hooks are per-repository and are never pushed. Similarly, the repo config isn't pushed either, nor is anything in `.git/info`, or a number of other things.

Pushing and pulling only exchanges branches/tags and commit objects (and anything reachable from a commit, e.g. trees, blobs).

Comment: Is there a way to have hooks in central and get them pulled on each clone, and applied.

Comment: @f1wade You could add a `.githooks` directory which would be version controlled then either sym-link or create wrapper hook scripts from inside `.git`.  Cloning wouldn't automatically wire in `.githooks` but once wired in you can push and pull new versions of the hook scripts.

Answer (score 56):

No, git hooks are not pushed or pulled, as they are not part of the repository code.

Please refer to [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for a list of simple client-side and server-side hooks.

If you want to enable some hooks for all clients that clone or pull from a given repository, you have to add the hooks to your codebase and then create your own script to copy them into, or link to them from `repo/.git/hooks/`.

Comment: but how does the copy script get called?

Comment: @AdamJohns It gets called by the user/developer, probably in the form of a `setup.sh` that the dev runs when they first clone the repository. After this, updates to the hooks can happen automatically by having a hook that re-runs an script updating them after every pull, for example. So you don't have to rely on the developer to do it themselves.

Answer (score 45):

Sadly no but since git 2.9 you can place them into .githooks folder (as others mentioned) and run:

```
git config --local core.hooksPath .githooks/
```

So no need to create symlinks or copy files.