# How to update prepare-commit-msg

Tags: git, githooks

This is so nice. And I would so much like to implement it on an existing repository.

But after changing it I get:

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/jarls_test'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

When doing git status. As I understand .git is not managed by git, which makes sense. But the hooks folder, now can I push it so that when someone new clones the repo the hooks are automatically installed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are git hooks pushed to the remote when I 'git push'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222186/are-git-hooks-pushed-to-the-remote-when-i-git-push)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+commit