# pre-commit.com hook to reject commit if a file contains a specific string

Tags: pre-commit.com

Is there already a [pre-commit.com](//pre-commit.com) hook to reject commit if a file contains a specific string?

I know how to do this with a git pre-commit hook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836281/633961

But I would like to go the pre-commit.com way because this would streamline my way to a way which is done by other developers.

For example I would like to use the same string which other people use, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [`language: pygrep`](https://pre-commit.com/#pygrep) hook.  This implements a regex matching againsta  file

`pygrep` is especially useful for a [`repo: local`](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks) hook which lives directly in your repository's `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file

an example which forbids `DONTSHIP`:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: dontship
        name: DONTSHIP check
        entry: DONTSHIP
        language: pygrep
        types: [text]
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit

Comment: How to check multiple strings using regex?

Comment: @Stack_IQ that's a separate and unrelated question, but `|`