# Can I generate warnings when we try to compare Java boxed primitives with "==" instead of ".equals"?

Tags: java, static-analysis, primitive, autoboxing

NPEs are described as a "billion dollar mistake". I have to believe a close second may be comparing boxed primitives with "==" instead of .equals(...).

When we have a part of our codebase that returns a `Long` instead of a `long`, for example:

```
class Car {
  Long speed;
}
```

and

```
Car carA, carB;
boolean res1 = carA.getSpeed() == carB.getSpeed(); // could fail if the speeds are equal because the wrappers are distinct.

boolean res2 = Objects.equals(carA.getSpeed(), carB.getSpeed()); // compares by value and works
```

this kind of thing is easy to miss in a PR. Is there a way to generate a warning to catch this situation? We use sonar, FWIW.

Comment: I would take a look at git pre-commit hooks. This is not a Java question, but a `git` question. More on a [solution that automatically rejects commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835998/git-hook-to-reject-commits-where-files-contain-a-specific-string) when a specific string exists. In your case, your PR (not sure what platform you use Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket etc) can display a warning in the PR thread if "==" exists.

Comment: @azbarcea Rejecting `==` is not workable; this is a context-sensitive question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the [spotbugs-maven-plugin](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which would make the build fail with *RC: Suspicious reference comparison (RC_REF_COMPARISON)* if it encounters code like this.

Comment: I somehow lost track of this great feature. It also spotted a few other important bugs in our system. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you use IntelliJ this will be warned by default

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html#code-maturity for mor details

Comment: Correct. I can see this being analyzed part of the code static validation (IDE plugin or Coverity or other static analyzers).

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use the [sonar server](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/community/) (community edition). There specific are rules for [equals](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java?search=equals). There are plugins (SonarLint) to connect your favourite IDEs and also [Plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/) for the server itself to add other features (like spotbugs etc).

(I am not affiliated with sonarqube but a user of the free sonar server)

Comment: SonarLint as IDE plugin you mean,