# Is there a way to display a message to an end-user when they commit a file in Git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

When anybody makes a change to a specific file in my Git repo, I'd like to display a message to the user when they commit or push via Git CLI.

Scenario: User alters `crazycalculations.py`, I'd like to say, "Hey, I notice you altered crazycalculations.py.  Did you have John in Accounting review your change?".  Just a friendly reminder to the end user that their messing with a file that is not to be messed with without supervision.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with git hooks. If you navigate to `.git/hooks` you'll see samples for shell code that can be run on specific git events. Check the `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample` will have some sample code you can use.

For example, at the top of `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
if git diff HEAD --name-only | grep -q "crazycalculations.py"; then
   echo "Are you sure you want to edit crazycalculations.py?"
   sleep 3
fi
```

[image]

**Documentation:**

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks for the example.  This is a useful, followup question - adding hooks to the repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository