# Pushing pre-commit git hook (Rubocop)

Tags: ruby, git, github, githooks, rubocop

I've currently configured my repository to use Rubocop for pre-commit linting by creating a *pre-commit* hook under `./git/hooks`

However, I'd like this to be available to everyone working on my team, and hence I'd like to push these changes to Github.

How do I go about pushing the changes related to pre-commit linting onto the remote repository without committing the `.git` folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting git hooks into repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fairly common practice when using git hooks to, for example, check in a `hooks/` directory. Then, users can symlink from `.git/hooks/foo` to `hooks/foo`.

You might even consider putting a shell script in the repository that creates the necessary symlinks when the user runs it. For example, `hooks/setup.sh` might run something like `ln -s ./foo ../.git/hooks/foo`.

Ultimately, though, each user would still have to take some action to set up his own hooks. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-repository) for more info).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a managed solution for pre-commit hook management like [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/).
Or a centralized solution for server-side git-hooks like [Datree.io](https://datree.io/solutions/devops-policy/).
It has built-in policies like:

1. Detect and prevent [merging of secrets](https://docs.datree.io/docs/do-not-include-secret-files).
2. Enforce proper [Git user configuration](https://docs.datree.io/docs/unverified-users).
3. Enforce [Jira ticket integration](https://docs.datree.io/docs/link-pull-request-to-a-jira-ticket) - mention ticket number in pull request name / commit message.

It won't replace all of your hooks, but it might help your developers with the most obvious ones without the configuration hell of installing the hooks on every 
developers computer/repo.

Disclaimer: I am one of Datrees founders