# Is it possible to enforce a signed commit locally?

Tags: git, digital-signature, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

My company uses GitHub for our organization repos and also validates authors by enforcing [signed commits](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits).

The problem is that it is *possible* to clone a repo, create a branch, submit several commits, and create a Pull Request without any signed commits.  It isn't until there is an attempt to merge that PR into `develop` or `main` or whatever is the branch protected with signed commits where the PR merge fails.  At that point, we have to clean it all up with a `rebase` so that there are no commits without signatures.

Is there a way to enforce the signatures even on the local clone of the repo?  Something like a pre-commit hook that ensures the commit fails if there is no signature?  Something that, once set up, would look something like this:

```sh
> git clone <my-company's-git-repo-with-signatures-required-on-main-branch>
> cd <my-company's-git-repo-with-signatures-required-on-main-branch>
> git switch main # Just to make it clear that I am on the protected branch
> touch my-new-file
> git add my-new-file
> git commit -m "Testing" # And this is for a user that does not have signing set up yet.
Git Error: Cannot commit without signature  # Or whatever the error message would be
```

This prevents any sort of "roll back" via `rebase` or whatever other method may be possible.

Comment: If your team is fine with a one-time setup for each developer on the project, git-hooks scripts can be put in the repository to share a pre-push / pre-commit hook for that, for example. See [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281447/10441671), [blog article with this approach](https://www.viget.com/articles/two-ways-to-share-git-hooks-with-your-team/)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not possible to force someone to create a signed commit, or things like that do the `force signed commit` check.

For this is your company repository, and signed commit is a MUST. U may want to make a rule: anyone who contribute to this repository should do signed commit.

FYI:
something u can do is to set a git alias for `normal commit` to a `signed commit`.

something like:

```
s-commit = !sh -c 'git commit -S $*'
```

even make commit always to a signed commit.. :-)

of cource any contribute should use or obey this rule..

Comment: Thanks for your input.  You are correct that we can ask it to be a rule, and it already is a rule.  I just wanted to automate things a little more so that no one can accidentally make a mistake.  Regarding the alias, that works fine for me, but not broadly across the company.