# How to push .git folder to remote repo?

Tags: git, hook

I want to create a server-side git hook to block direct push to remote main branch. I look through some blogs and find it can be done by creating a .git/hooks folder and put a script named "update" within that folder on remote repo(Refer to this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#server-side-hooks)).

Firstly, I try to push local .git folder to remote repo. But even with command `git add .git`and confirm .git is NOT in .gitignore file, it has not been push to remote repo with regular operations.
So my questions is how could I create .git folder in remote repo and put some scripts into .git/hooks subdirectory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting Git hooks into a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-a-repository) (In short, the way you suggest is not not how you do it, and yes, it does make it annoying.)

Comment: I looks through the post you give bt can't find the desired answer. Let me explain a little bit. Currently, I do have a remote repo without .git folder. And I want to add .git folder into remote repo so I can add hooks into .git/hooks folder, thus it can run on server side. But it could not be created by pushing a local .git folder to remote(at least from what I tried)..

Comment: You cannot push `.git/` folder with `git` commands. And you don't need to. Init a new git repo at the remote side using `git init`, then push your branches, commits and tags.

Comment: @XiaomingLiu I know that's what you _think you want_ to do, but you cannot. The linked post is the way to get your hooks into git, and you must then have your users install them.